# How to add data to an array without push because it returns the length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Simple. I have this array and I am trying to add a value to it but when I use push it just returns the length of the array after I push the value. I remember finding a way around this with a different function but I cannot remember what it was.

I will give a bit of context:

```
function submitCommentHandler() {
        firestore.collection("posts").doc(title).update({
            comments: comments.concat(newComment)
        })

        navigate("/all-posts");
    }
```

There is the function to add a comment, but when I run that function it changes the value of comments in the firestore db to a number instead of the full array. If the value of the comments changes to a number I cannot access the text within the comments.

I decided to just do `comments.push(newComment)` and then set the comments to comments in the object. I think thats what some people were telling me.

Comment: It is for a project where people post stuff then you can comment and stuff. I am using firestore so when I display the comments it shows the number 1 when I add the first comment onto a post instead of the actual text of the comment.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't use the return value, `push` with modify the array, so after `push` just use the original array reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @Endzeit This doesn't even warrant an example, it's simple Javascript

Comment: When I use the push method it sets the value of the array to a number when I need the array so I can display it. When it sets the value of the array to a number I can't display the comments. For example: I want to show the array of users  that I store in my firestore db but when I add a user it sets the firestore value of users to a number (then number of users) which makes it impossible for me to display the users separately because it just holds the number not the users names.

Comment: @Dexygen I'm just wondering about the context. As you've pointed out in your comment, one can simply ignore the return value if not needed. Maybe the OP is required to use a single statement for some reason. I cannot grab the problem at hand, because just ignoring the return value seems not to suffice. A little more context would make this clear.

Comment: I added a bit of context in the question.

Comment: If you are looking for a one-liner, you can write `comments: (comments.push(newComment), comments)`, but if `comments: comments.concat(newComment)` already doesn't work, you will have the exact same problem. Moreover, keep in mind that `comments.push(...)` changes the original array (side effect), unlike `comments.concat(...)` (no side effect).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `push()` to add a value to an array, the value is pushed to the original array.

```js
const values = [1];
const pushValue = values.push(2);

console.log(pushValue); // 2
console.log(values); // [1, 2]
```

Comment: Yes but when I am storing it in a firestore db it doesnt only return the number but set the array to a number (the length of the array)